# std::forward_list swap() implementation in C++11

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

My assumption is that in a `std::list<>` the `swap` function for the list itself is done by swapping the anchor node. The node can access the previous node and update the previous node's next pointer easily to point to the anchor of the other list; but this cannot be done in `std::forward_list` (well, it can be, it is just very costly).

If my assumption is correct, how is `swap()` implemented in `std::forward_list` in an efficient manner? And while we are at it, how is `swap()` implemented for the `iterator`s of `std::forward_list`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `std::forward_list` is simply a singly-linked rather than doubly-linked list like `std::list`, therefore you can simply swap the `head` and `tail` pointers of the list to accomplish a `swap()` operation.

Comment: I was under the impression that `std::list` was internally a circular list and I assumed the same for `std::forward_list`. I am guessing that is entirely implementation dependant.

Comment: Even if they were circular linked lists there'd still be no need to update any pointers on the nodes themselves. The whole list is being swapped so none of the node links will change. All that changes are the pointers from the `std::list`s to the nodes.

Comment: @bames53: If it is a circular list, then each node is pointing to the next node or the tail of the list. And the tail of the list is pointing the head which in turn points to the first element. Then how do you swap the tail pointer because you need to adjust the node that is pointing to the tail and you can't get to it unless you traverse the whole list. Or is the tail pointer an object that points to the head as well as the last node?

Comment: @Samaursa: I don't see why you need to traverse the entire list to change the `tail` pointer even if `std::forward_list` is a circular list.  A pointer is just pointing to an element ... In this case the tail-pointer is pointing to the last element node.  If I swap that value with another tail-pointer, now the tail-pointer is pointing to the last node in another list.  The same would be true for the head-pointer.  There is no need to traverse the list and update the rest of the elements, because they're all pointing to each other in a circular fashion on the heap, and that's just fine.

Comment: @Jason: I see what you mean. To distinguish the _end-of-list_ from the rest, I keep checking each node against the tail pointer. Makes sense. I had a completely different implementation which I realized now is incompatible with `forward_list`. In my implementation, there is no tail. The head is a dummy node that is pointing to itself if the list is empty, or pointing to the first node. The last node points to the dummy node. This causes problems if I want to have the nodes be singly linked. Thanks for clearing it up! (+1)

Comment: I guess it depends on the implementation, because I think you're describing a linked list that uses sentry nodes where swapping lists can't swap the sentry nodes. If the circular linked list has the last node point at the first node, then the last node doesn't need updating when lists are swapped.

Answer (score 3):

This is completely implementation-specific, but if the forward lists are implemented by having the class just store a pointer to the first and last linked list cells, then swap could just swap those two pointers.  Since forward-linked lists don't have any back pointers, there aren't any more updates to be made and the whole operation can be done in O(1).

As for swap with iterators, this doesn't actually exchange the linked list cells between the two lists; it just has the first iterator point to the cell referenced by the second iterator and vice-versa.  If you want to swap the values being pointed at, then this can be done by just modifying the objects in the linked list cells so that they change values.  You don't need to rewire the lists in any way.

Hope the helps!

Comment: Ah, of course! I was getting the `iterator`s confused with the nodes themselves for some reason, (+1)

Comment: I believe forward_list doesn't even have to store a tail pointer, but can use a generic empty iterator as the end iterator.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confused (or I am confused as to what you're asking). std::forward_list::swap(std::forward_list& other) is trivial, with each list object exchanging pointers to the head of their list (and any other member variables) - just like std::list.

The iterator object doesn't have a swap method. The contained object might, or may use the global swap method - but that operates on the objects, and doesn't mutate the list itself or its nodes.